# iphone web services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to have a web service so that my iPhone app can be linked to the database to allow me to do these functions :

1. login/logout for member
2. registering as member
3. retrieving profile from database
4. retrieve image from the database

I am very unsure on how to do this, some guides or a paid company who does the functions above would be very welcome.

Comment: its not a question regarding iphone

Comment: I agree Rakesh. Try php or .net webservices.

Comment: @rakeshNS totally agree too, changed the tags to: php, web-services, .net, web-development but my edit was strangely rejected.

Answer (score 0):

For Web Services this is the best way, Use this link

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Just read it, this is very easy and simple way for the mentioned web-services.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code like the below in php and use the NSURL to connect with the server.

in Xcode:

```
NSError        *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://Yourserveraddress/demo/adminemailvalidation.php?email=%@&type=%@",Email.text,@"admin"]; //here you have to bind the parameters.
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSData *serverReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Based on the serverReply data you have to validate the credentials.

ServerSide:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','pikesol','india12345');
mysql_select_db('pikesol_india');
$FamilyName=$_GET['familyname'];
$Authenticated=$_GET['authenticated'];

if(!empty($FamilyName) &&!empty($Authenticated))
{
$query=mysql_query("select FirstName,LastName,Email from memberrequests where FamilyName ='$FamilyName'  and  Authenticated ='$Authenticated' ");
$var ;

 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
 if ($num_rows >0) 
 {
 $xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
$xml_output .= "<entries>";

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $xml_output .= "<entry>";
    $xml_output .= "<firstname>".$row['FirstName']."</firstname>";
     $xml_output .= "<lastname>".$row['LastName']."</lastname>";
    $xml_output .= "<email>".$row['Email']."</email>";
    $xml_output .= "</entry>";
    }
$xml_output .= "</entries>";
echo $xml_output; 
 }
  else
  {
  $var='No';
  echo $var; 
}
 } 
?>
```

Comment: "You have to write the code like the below in php and use the NSURL to connect with the server." - you do not HAVE TO do this at all, it is just one of MANY options/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

i did deal with a web-service in one of my applications to register new users, login/logout, fetch some data .. the web-service was written in .Net and i deal with it through soap messages .. if you are interested i will explain it more for you .. good luck.